# Push array object values into new arrays

Tags: javascript

I have `data` array object and two arrays `scoreData` and `titleData` as follows

```
scoreData=[]
titleData = []

data = [ 
{score:1, title: tesh},
 {score:2, title: teshu}, 
{score:3, title: teshiti} ]
```

I Wanted to push `score` and `title` values into `scoreData` and `titleData` respectively.

So the expected output will be

```
scoreData = [1,2,3]
titleData = [tesh,teshu,teshiti]
```

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: What did you try to solve this? Where did you got stuck?

Comment: Itried this data.map((item) => {
      sereiesData.push(item?.score);
      categoryData.push(item?.event);
    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scoreData = data.map(({score}) => score);
titleData = data.map(({title}) => title);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use use `forEach` for doing it in one loop rather than two separate loops.

```
data.forEach(obj => {
    scoreData.push(obj.score)
    titleData.push(obj.title)
})
```